# LaTeX Как сделать "необрабатываемую" строку

Tags: latex

У меня есть проблема , я хочу чтобы латех не обрабатывал ровно одну строку C:\WORK\Examples\SEntember1 и вставил её в текст полностью без изменений

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{verbatim}
C:\WORK\Examples\SEntember1
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Только, если верить Львовскому, это опасные команды, во всяком случае, про окружение точно помню, что от него может зависнуть комп. Ну, и пакет нужно подключить соответствующий.

Comment: @Grek79 TEX - это обычное приложение, которое можно и снять, и перезапустить. В то же время MathJAX может серьёзно тормозить работу компьютера.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё аналогом окружения verbatim является команда `\verb`, если не требуется выделение текста из строки:

```
\verb|C:\WORK\Examples\SEntember1|
```